# Are babel decorators the same as TypeScript's?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I code with TypeScript a lot, but less babel, I know how TypeScript works on decorators, and babel also support decorators, do they act the same?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are the same, in a sense that they produce the same behavior, but they have different implementations.

Both follow ECMAScript specifications and bring features early to us. You can expect what is on both of them to probably be supported by node or the browser in the future.

Code:

```
function f() {
  console.log("f(): evaluated");
  return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
      console.log("f(): called");
  }
}

function g() {
  console.log("g(): evaluated");
  return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
      console.log("g(): called");
  }
}

class C {
  @f()
  @g()
  method() {}
}

new C().method();
```

TypeScript output:

```
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
function f() {
    console.log("f(): evaluated");
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        console.log("f(): called");
    };
}
function g() {
    console.log("g(): evaluated");
    return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
        console.log("g(): called");
    };
}
class C {
    method() { }
}
__decorate([
    f(),
    g()
], C.prototype, "method", null);
new C().method();
```

Babel output:

```
"use strict";

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _dec, _dec2, _desc, _value, _class;

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _applyDecoratedDescriptor(target, property, decorators, descriptor, context) {
  var desc = {};
  Object['ke' + 'ys'](descriptor).forEach(function (key) {
    desc[key] = descriptor[key];
  });
  desc.enumerable = !!desc.enumerable;
  desc.configurable = !!desc.configurable;

  if ('value' in desc || desc.initializer) {
    desc.writable = true;
  }

  desc = decorators.slice().reverse().reduce(function (desc, decorator) {
    return decorator(target, property, desc) || desc;
  }, desc);

  if (context && desc.initializer !== void 0) {
    desc.value = desc.initializer ? desc.initializer.call(context) : void 0;
    desc.initializer = undefined;
  }

  if (desc.initializer === void 0) {
    Object['define' + 'Property'](target, property, desc);
    desc = null;
  }

  return desc;
}

function f() {
  console.log("f(): evaluated");
  return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    console.log("f(): called");
  };
}

function g() {
  console.log("g(): evaluated");
  return function (target, propertyKey, descriptor) {
    console.log("g(): called");
  };
}

var C = (_dec = f(), _dec2 = g(), (_class = function () {
  function C() {
    _classCallCheck(this, C);
  }

  _createClass(C, [{
    key: "method",
    value: function method() {}
  }]);

  return C;
}(), (_applyDecoratedDescriptor(_class.prototype, "method", [_dec, _dec2], Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(_class.prototype, "method"), _class.prototype)), _class));


new C().method();
```

Output after run:

```
> ts-node ts-example.ts
f(): evaluated
g(): evaluated
g(): called
f(): called

> node babel-example.js
f(): evaluated
g(): evaluated
g(): called
f(): called
```

Comment: So now they are the same, one more question, since when that JavaScript supports `Array.prototype.forEach`? Are class definition and forEach both supported in the same version? Why babel uses ES5 function instead of ES6 class since it can use forEach.

Comment: Are Angular decorators the same as those in `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` with the `legacy` option set to `true`? I guess they are not, but I am not sure... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the latest state of the decorators, but half year ago Babel and TypeScript decorators where different in behavior in some cases. Decorators is not 
a specification yet, it is only [Stage 2](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). That's why in TypeScript decorators is an experimental feature.

For example, non enumerable from [core-decorators](https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators) didn't work in TypeScript some time ago. And almost all decorators, that applied to the fields.

So the answer is: "they are similar, but not equal". Do not suggest, that you write one decorator, and it will work similar in babel and TypeScript. Until it will be standardized and realizations will match the standard.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are different. Babel don't support parameter decorators, and TS's property decorators don't support the initializer for a property.